# Validate email, addeventlistener keyup function

Tags: javascript, validation, email, addeventlistener, keyup

I have done this function that allow me to validate a email input. It shows a error message until email is correctly written. When it is correct message is deleted. But if I delete the email of the input, the error message remains. I have tried with a if(input.value === "") but nothing. I would be very grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

```
    const email = document.querySelector('#email');

    eventListeners();

    function eventListeners() {
      email.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
    }

    function validateEmail() {

      const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
        inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
        formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
        email.removeChild(document.querySelector('.error'));
        alert("Valid email address!");
      } else {
        if (!document.querySelector('.error')) {

          if (inputEmail === "") {
            email.removeChild(document.querySelector('.error'));
          } else {
            const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
            errorMessage.setAttribute('class', 'error');
            errorMessage.innerHTML = `<p>error</p>`;
            email.insertBefore(errorMessage, email.childNodes[4]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```
    <div class="campo email">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
```

---

I edit my question, now it works.

```js
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
  email.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
}

function validateEmail() {

  const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
    inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
    formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
    email.removeChild(document.querySelector('.error'));
    alert("Valid email address!");
  } else {
    if (!document.querySelector('.error')) {
      const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
      errorMessage.setAttribute('class', 'error');
      errorMessage.innerHTML = `<p>error</p>`;
      email.insertBefore(errorMessage, email.childNodes[4]);
    } else if (inputEmail.value === "") {
      email.removeChild(document.querySelector('.error'));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="campo email">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
```